# Selenium check if WhatsApp file upload if completed

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

in my C# application in using Selenium to send files on web.whatsapp.

I send multiple files to multiple numbers and this is problem. Because sometimes when user's internet is not fast, then it will redirect to another chat before it finish uploading file.

I tried to check for div element where is that 'loading circle' -> if it exist -> don't redirect

Problem is that selector path is always different for that div so it won't work this way.

Do anyone have any ideas? Or some way to check if file is already uploaded? Maybe some javascript that returns if any file is being uploaded on website?
Thank you so much for all answers and have a nice day :)

Comment: I had one more idea that I will send on multiple tabs, but problem is that when you open whatsapp web on another tab, then whatsapp will be blocked on previous tab.

Comment: Please share what you tried in the code. That way its easy for people to answer.
A suggestion for your issue is, why not use 2 or 3 different chromedrivers, so that for one whatsapp window, you will do in chrome, and for 2nd, you can use firefox. You can open and handle two or more windows in selenium.

Comment: Also try to access that div, with text or any other attribute like class. I also suspect that reaching out to that div via By.Xpath selector would be more efficient since you are not getting a hold of that div. By.Xpath will always look for that div in that particular hireachy.